# How do i write code in ASP.NET MVC to check whether user accepeted terms and condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC project I need to write code to check for users whether they accept terms and condition. I am using Entity framework and Database first approach. I have Table called **Appterms**, in which I have field called **TermsAccepted** and **Date**. I also have other fields in Appterms table such as  **GatewayUserId** and **termId**. ' GatewayUserID has ID of registered users and termId is primary key. 'Termsaccepted' field is of bit type.

I tried to follow custom attribute function which is posted in this post 
[MVC 3 How can I make a user view a warning/disclaimer screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967981/mvc-3-how-can-i-make-a-user-view-a-warning-disclaimer-screen) but not able to implement as per my needs.

I am using this post [Getting current user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924692/how-do-you-get-the-userid-of-a-user-object-in-asp-net-mvc) to get id of current user. So after this how can i return 0 or 1 to check they accepted terms and condition.

This is the code snippet I am trying to use :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, 
Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AcceptedTermsCheck : ActionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Check if AcceptedTC is set to true

    // If set, then do nothing

    // Otherwise redirect to TC page
    }
 }
```

Here to check if user accepted terms, i should return true, that is '1' in my GatewayUserId field, if not it should return false.But I don't know how to do this. And also I got to know I should create session to achieve this task. But never worked on it before.

Any help??
Thanks..

Comment: I edited question and added source which i referred to solve this problem.But no success..

Comment: The logic shown in the comments in your code should work. What are you currently having trouble with?

Comment: You appear to have the right idea on how to do this - what is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: @CodeCaster  My problem is till now i just figured it out the logic of this.But don't know how to implement. I am having problem in setting values in my database field, gatewayUserId 0 or 1 based on if it returns true or false. And also I am thinking do i need to use session to store user decision that is whether they accepted terms and condition. Will it make any sense to my problem??

Comment: @james I posted my problem in previous comment.Can you have a look into that..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do. you can post back data or use jquery to post to a action to check and if the terms are accepted and then enable the submit button for a better user experience. Whichever way you choose, you can do something like this.

```
var dataEntityModel = new YoursEntities();
            AppTerm currentTerm = dataEntityModel.Appterms.ToList().
where(x=>x.GatewayUserId == yourCurrentUserID
&& x.termid == yourTermId).FirstOrDefault();

if(currentTerm.TermsAccepted == true)
{

}
else
{
   RedirectToAction("action","controller");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userlogin login = db.userlogins.Where(j => j.email == name && j.password == password && j.status == 1)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```